# How to show content based on radio buttons using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

If I create two radio buttons for example:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, "false") Male
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, "true") Female
```

How can I show one div when true is pressed, hide it and show another one if false is pressed?

I created pretty simple web site to test this:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Testi
<div>

        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.isTest, "false", new { id = "male" })


        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.isTest, "true", new { id = "female" })


        if (Model.isTest)
        {
            <div>
                Testdiv
            </div>
        }



</div>
```

Simple model:

```
public class Testi
{
    public bool isTest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You would have do this via javascript because Razor is serverside and only runs when the page loads. Please show what you have tried though; otherwise, this question will most likely be closed.

Comment: Your update will only work with the current value when the page loads. You will need to add javascript to handle the users actions and the changing of the interface as desired. There are plenty of examples of how to handle user clicks on radio buttons on SO. If you do a little searching, you can probably find the help you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript. Add an `onclick` event to the two radio buttons and call a JavaScript function passing the value of the radio button:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, "false", new { onclick = "showNote(this.value);" }) Male
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsFemale, "true", new { onclick = "showNote(this.value);" }) Female
```

Then add those two `div`s that you want to show/hide:

```
<div id="male">Notes for men</div>
<div id="female">Notes for women</div>
```

And finally add the JavaScript function that will do the job:

```
<script>
  function showNote(isFemale) {
    var male = document.getElementById("male");
    var female = document.getElementById("female");
    if (isFemale == "true") {
      female.style.display = "block";
      male.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      male.style.display = "block";
      female.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```